# CSS - How do I set a limit to how many LI's in a UL list before it should move to the next column

Tags: css, wordpress

If I have a website which lists endless options in a UL, how can I force say a limit of 10 before it should move to the next column[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PifZv.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say your list is

```
<ul>
  <li>item #1</li>
  <li>item #2</li>
  <li>item #3</li>
  ...
  <li>item #22</li>
  <li>item #23</li>
</ul>
```

You could use `Flexbox` by setting a column direction and a `flex-basis` of `10%` (so every `list-item` takes 1/10 of the available height before shifting into a new column) which acts as a limit

```
ul { 
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }

li { 
  flex-basis: 10%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZPLBM)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="width:50%;float:left">
    <ul> 
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%;float:left">
    <ul> 
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: in style, make body, html {width:100%}